# Centering CSS Floats

Tags: css, css-float

Can anyone figure out why these images won't float in the centre? I've floated everything left so that things aren't cleared, but margin:auto and text-align:centre; seem to be having no effect.

I would like the margins on both sides of the group of images to be the same as shown in this screenshot db.tt/aNu8zBVl

Many thanks - here's the JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/UWYv3/3/

---

*EDIT*

I would like the margins on both sides of the group of images to be the same:

[image: Image of how I want it to look]

Comment: `text-align` refers to the *content* of the element, and has no effect on its placement.

Answer (score 3):

The code that you posted at jsfiddle.net will *tile* the images.  In that regard, it's working fine.

*Can you provide a picture of what you are **trying** to achieve?*

You have a typo, as Marc B pointed out: `text-align: center` (not *centre*).

**However, `text-align:center` won't have any affect on the `<img>` because they are floated.**

Here are 2 examples to illustrate this principle:

1. [This example is floated, but also has `clear: left` so there will only be one image per line.](http://jsfiddle.net/UWYv3/5/) (Perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve?) I left `text-align:center` to demonstrate that it has no effect on floated elements.
2. [This example is not floated](http://jsfiddle.net/UWYv3/6/), and as you can see, `text-align:center` is doing it's job.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I would like the margins on both sides of the group of images to be the same. Does this make things clearer...? http://db.tt/aNu8zBVl